# Printing text at the bottom of the next page

Tags: atbegshi

I am having some trouble placing text at the bottom of the next page. For some reason, the text is being printed at the bottom of the current page. I tried nesting but it only works for the first printing on next page command. Please help me fix this.

```
        \documentclass{article}
        \usepackage{atbegshi}
        \usepackage{blindtext}
        \usepackage{picture}

        \newcommand{\printnextpage}[1]{
        {\LARGE to print on bottom of next page }


        \AtBeginShipoutNext{%
        \AtBeginShipoutUpperLeft{%
         \put(0.1\paperwidth,-0.95\paperheight){#1}%
         }%
        }
        }

        \begin{document}
        \blindtext[2]
        \printnextpage{i am at bottom}
        \blindtext[7]
        \printnextpage{im at bottom too}
        \blindtext[9]
        \end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

The current page *is* the next page, which will be output next.
You can nest `\AtBeginShipoutNext`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{picture}

\newcommand{\printnextpage}[1]{%
  {\LARGE to print on bottom of next page }%
  \par
  \AtBeginShipoutNext{%
    \AtBeginShipoutNext{%
      \AtBeginShipoutUpperLeft{%
        \put(0.1\paperwidth,-0.95\paperheight){#1}%
      }%
    }%  
  }%
}

\begin{document}
\blindtext[2]
\printnextpage{i am at bottom}
\blindtext[7]
\end{document}
```

Another more complicate method: (Absolute) page numbers can be remembered in references and a `\AtBeginShipout` would check the reference to know, when it has to print the text.

Comment: it works only for the first \printnextpage, if i add more it doest work as expected.

Comment: @EphraimNcory: I do not know, what you expect. If `\printnextpage` is used twice, then the second text will overwrite the first text, because they are placed at the same location.

Comment: just edited the MWE, run it and you will get an idea of what i mean

Comment: @EphraimNcory: Asynchronous output routine: `\printnextpage` has two parts: `\AtBeginShipoutNext` is executed right away, but the text before can go on this or later pages. The way via references is more robust regarding the asynchronous output routine. But can you clarify the purpose of the whole exercise? I not sure that `atbegshi` is the right approach. There are other ways like mark registers that could provide a better solution depending on the use case scenario.

Comment: all i am trying to achieve is provide a command which when called will print some text provided as an argument at the bottom of the next page, care to shed some light into those other ways to achieve what i want.